# Может ли GUID совпасть?

Tags: guid

Хотя уникальность каждого отдельного GUID не гарантируется, общее количество уникальных ключей настолько велико (2<sup>128</sup> или 3,4028×10<sup>38</sup>), что вероятность того, что в мире будут независимо сгенерированы два совпадающих ключа, крайне мала.

Как его изменить (модифицировать) чтобы он вообще никогда не мог совпасть?

Comment: Как бы вы его не модифицировали он рано или поздно совпадет. Хороший вопрос.

Comment: А должны не совпасть только с теми, которые вы генерируете для себя или вообще с любыми сгенерированными в мире?

Comment: в идеале со всеми

Comment: Если нужен действительно уникальный идентификатор, то зацените [URI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI) (URN, URL).

Comment: Насколько не увеличивай битовую длину, шанс повторения 2^битовая длина

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если вопрос чисто теоретический, то изменить (модифицировать) GUID, так чтобы он вообще никогда не мог совпасть - невозможно.

Если практический, прибавьте к нему timestamp и уникальный id клиента (того, кто генерирует id, например id телефона или жесткого диска).

Для хранения второго числа можно использовать отдельное поле. Сравнивать разумеется надо сразу оба поля. Теоретически этим мы нарушим правило 128 бит в GUID, но практически мы застрахуемся, например, от неверного алгоритма получения случайных чисел и даже при супер больших данных не получим коллизии.

Насколько я помню в WinAPI при генерации итак учитывается timestamp и id устройства.

Впрочем, вероятность коллизии и с обычным GUID итак пренебрежительно мала.

Comment: -1 В этом нет никакого смысла, так вероятность совпадения этих GUID нереально мала. Зато вы осложните алгоритм этими действиями.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov я понимаю, но автор вопроса четко сказал "чтобы он вообще никогда не мог совпасть".

Comment: Да ну это же нереально. Поэтому честный ответ на вопрос: "нет, это практически нереально.".

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Согласен, но очень сильно уменьшить шансы можно (почти до невозможности). Если прибегнуть к аналогии - человеку, который спрашивает как 100% не утонуть в море можно сказать, что гарантировать это нереально, а можно предложить поселится как можно дальше от моря и никогда не приближаться к нему.
В данном случае добавление timestamp и id устройства значительно уменьшат шансы случайной генерации одинакового GUID. Случайное повторение GUID возможно например, в случае ошибки в алгоритме генерации случайных чисел.

Answer (score 13):

Невозможно.

Дело в том, что GUID имеет фиксированную длину 128 бит. Всего разных 128-битных чисел ровно 2<sup>128</sup>. Допустим, вы смогли создать «идеальный» генератор GUID'ов. Запустите его на генерацию 2<sup>128</sup> + 1 числа. Из них, понятно, какие-то два из них [совпадут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%94%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%BB%D0%B5_(%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)).

Для того, чтобы числа никогда не повторялись, они, как минимум, должны быть неограниченной битовой длины.

Comment: а они же могут совпасть в пределах этого количества 2 128 ?

Comment: @codename0082016: Ну да, в этих пределах тоже могут, но не обязательно. Но тут зависит от алгоритма. Например, если алгоритм сначала выдаёт число 0, потом 1, потом 2 и т. д., то вначале не совпадут.

Comment: Так себе обоснование. Генерация guid'а в windows занимает 50 мс. чтобы сгенерировать 2^128 гуидов понадобится более 5 * 10^39 лет.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну так идеальный генератор может быть быстрым, `inc eax`. Уже лучше. Теперь поставим кластер. Ну и требование ТС не «не повторяется в течение _x_ лет», а «не повторяется вообще».

Comment: Там 50 мс как раз чтобы уникальность обеспечить - какая-то штука с грануляцией таймстемпов.

Comment: @Qwertiy - а откуда информация про 50 мс на гуид?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, не помню, где-то читал. Просто если взять меньший интервал, то гуиды совпадут (или могут совпасть) из-за использования времени в алгоритме генерации, поэтому винда обеспечивает каким-то образом эту задержку намеренно. Если найдёшь, дай ссылку?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov 100 наносекунд достаточно -микрософт взял половину от требуемого(соломку подстелили?): первоисточник, стандарт OSF (конкретно - DCE RPC). вам в раздел "Clock Overrun" http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9629399/apdxa.htm

Comment: @Qwertiy  раздел "Clock Overrun" http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9629399/apdxa.htm

Answer (score 3):

Уникальность обычно гарантируется двумя вещами, на выбор:

1. Сравнением. Генерируете и проверяете, что такого ещё нет.
2. Зависимостью от какой нибудь однозначной переменной, например время. ( DateTime.Now.Ticks )

Понятно, что оба способа имеют свои проблемы, но они в целом решаемы, если вы конечно не математическое обоснование чего-то в дипломе пишете.

Comment: Имейте ввиду, что время не однозначно - переводы часов, неправильные пояса на машине и всё такое.

Comment: @Kromster а никто не требует явного соответствия время - гуид. Можно просто сделать их зависимыми.

Comment: Вы пишите, что уникальность гарантируется или сравнением, или, например, временем. Мой комментарий относится вот к этой части - если считаеть время однозначным и гарантией уникальности, то тут возможна ошибка, т.к. время НЕ однозначно, и соответственно, не может гарантировать уникальность.

Comment: @Kromster я же написал, что зависимостью. Добавьте ко времени уникальный ключ машины + какую-нибудь ещё гадость -- гуиды будут вполне уникальны. Время тут скорее как облегчающий фактор, который в рамках работы здесь и сейчас будет давать строго уникальные гуиды.