# Уникальность ключей Guid.NewGuid

Tags: c#

Насколько уникальны ключи, генерируемые методом `Guid.NewGuid()` ?

Какова вероятность генерации двух одинаковых ключей методом `Guid.NewGuid()`?

Comment: Вот тут уже ответили на этот вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/686052/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-guid-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C

Comment: вижу, спасибо !

Comment: Вероятность генерации двух одинаковых GUID околонулевая. Вот еще ссылка https://stackoverflow.com/q/39771/12888024

Comment: Для тех, кому интересен вопрос уникальности GUID в .NET, можно почитать [здесь](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080627-00/?p=21823).